# how can I make a player hidden by terrain always visible?

Tags: unity-game-engine, terrain

I am making a 3D isometric game, in my game, there is a lot of holes and the player can go into them, but the problem is when he goes into one of them he becomes invisible, I can,t move the camera it will change the concept I tried using shader like the one in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S5gdvibmsV0) but it makes the entire terrain transparent and glitchy (I am using unity terrain) so I am stuck and I need Idea how to make the layer visible inside the hole

Comment: Have you tried using a different camera as soon as the player gets in a hole to render everything else but the terrain?

Comment: @MylonasK. thank you for your reply, no I actually don't know how or what that suppose to be

Comment: A video or screenshot of the current behaviour would help answers.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking can be achieved in multiple ways, depending on your render pipeline and requirements.

If you're working with the Universal Render Pipeline (URP), you could create a [Forward Renderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@10.1/manual/urp-forward-renderer.html) asset and create [a custom render pass](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GAh225QNpm0) whenever your player is occluded by terrain.

You could assign a new Layer to the player, such as "Player", then select or deselect said mask from the Filters > Layer Mask properties of the `Forward Render Data`. Then assign the same or a custom material for when the player is occluded by terrain.

[image: Forward Renderer Data]

Alternatively, you could create either a [cutout](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jidloC6gyf8) or a [dither](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szsWx9IQVDI) shader using [Shader Graph](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/shader-graph.html), on which there are many tutorials

Comment: thank you for your reply I tied to work with ShaderGraph but that is what gave me the error, the terrain is automatically generated using Houdini Engine so the terrain is lake handly drawn using terrain brushes it has no shader graph related, and if I try to replace the original material(URP/terrain/lit) it goes all transparent

Comment: I haven't worked with `Houdini Engine` terrain generation, but even if it's dynamically generated it will still work with the Forward Renderer solution. And you could always assign its GameObject layer through code `houdiniTerrain.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Terrain")`

Comment: Ok I'll try it out

Answer (score 0):

Camera GameObjects give you the option to select what layer you want them to "see" (render) using [the culling mask](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-cullingMask.html). Think of layers as grouping GameObjects and giving that group a name.

You can have multiple cameras at the same time each one with a different name and different layer to render, or even change the viewing layer of a single camera depending on changes happening in the game.

Assign a layer tag in each of the terrain elements in your scene and have the camera render them accordingly and "cull" the rest.

Very helpful [documentation on layers and camera culling mask](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/use-layers.html).

Comment: thank you for your explanation, but won,t this make a whole terrain invisible, I don't understand how will I use it to solve my problem

Comment: @Dev Your problem was seeing the player through terrain. Many isometric games make the container terrain dissapear (How to survive 2 comes to mind, where it makes walls transparent when you get to another room through the door). So your question makes it look like you want that. Do you need your player to be visible through terrain.. like an X-ray kind of thing instead? Can you please reform your question a bit clearer?

Comment: I want my player to be completely visible not like an X-ray and w part of the terrain also visible, if he's inside a hole I want the see the player inside that hole and I want to see the ground and the hole walls